# How to give permissions to other user after logging as root in Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, permissions, sudo

I am a linux newbie and I have a very basic question. I have one machine which is `machineA` and I have a root access to that machine.

Now I need to create these below two directories and give permissions to `app` user.

```
Create ZooKeeper Data directory and give permissions to app : /opt/zookeeper/data
Create ZooKeeper Log directory and give permissions to app : /opt/zookeeper/log
```

I have already created those directories in `/opt folder` by logging as root -

```
root@machineA:/opt# ls -lt
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Dec 17 13:46 zookeeper

root@machineA:/opt/zookeeper# ls -lt
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 17 13:46 log
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 17 13:45 data
```

Now I am not sure how to give permissions to `app` user as mentioned above? I believe this is pretty easy question but I am not sure how to do that?

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
chown -R app /opt/zookeeper
```

This will *change owner* of the `/opt/zookeeper` directory and all its subdirectories to `app`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `chown` to change the owner of a file (or directory):

```
chown app log data
```